# 404 Error while accessing the font files

Tags: themes, css, 404-error

Added a custom font as follows

1. Uploaded web-font files and given them the 777 permission

   `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/`
2. Added rules to the css file

   `@font-face {
       font-family: 'museo_sans700';
       src: url('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/museosans_700-webfont.eot');
       src: url('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/museosans_700-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/museosans_700-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/museosans_700-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/fonts/museosans_700-webfont.svg#museo_sans700') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       }`

However, while using/accessing the font family, it gives a 404 error

Attached snap 
[image]

Any clue?? Why this is happening??

Comment: Who owns the files?  root or the user whose directory the files live in?

Answer (score 2):

Please use short path file url rather then absolute path.

So code is like:

```
@font-face{ /* for IE */
font-family:FontFamily;
src:url(Font.eot);
}
@font-face { /* for non-IE */
font-family:FontFamily;
src:url(http://) format("No-IE-404"),url(Font.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Make sure that readable web has released it’s first @font-face related software utility for creating natively compressed EOT files quickly and easily.

If this is not your solution then you need to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your server is not allowing to load woff and woff2 fonts.

Please check this documentation. It has server config to enable woff and woff in Azure. https://base16solutions.wordpress.com/2017/11/09/issue-of-fonts-not-loading-on-azure-sites/

Answer (score 0):

404 stands for file are not available at the URL you are trying to access it. check your file path and files in your given directory.

also check permissions:
permission for file:644
directory: 755

Comment: All files are in correct places, check this link http://tinyurl.com/phsgbxt

I have changed the permissions as well, but no guess